# Google sheets Python quickstart, configure OAuth, can't select "Internal"

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

I am a brand new Google Developer (but not new to programming or Python).
I am trying to learn a bit about Google Sheets (Python API).

I found the following Quickstart document: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python?authuser=3

I have Python locally installed (Python 3.7.3).
I created a Google developer account, created a project, found the Google Sheets API in the API Library and enabled it for my project.

I'm am trying to complete the fourth bullet point under "Prerequisites" of that Quickstart document:

- Authorization credentials for a desktop application. To learn how to create credentials for a desktop application, refer to Create credentials.

where 'Create credentials' is a link to this document:
https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-credentials?authuser=3

I am stuck on the 6th step there:

To configure the OAuth consent screen:

1. Open the Google Cloud Console.
2. Next to Google Cloud Platform, click the Down arrow arrow_drop_down and select a project.
3. At the top-left corner, click Menu menu.
4. Click APIs & Services > Credentials. The credential page for your project appears.
5. Click Configure Consent Screen. The "OAuth consent screen" screen appears.
6. Click the user type for your app. If you're running a Quickstart, select Internal.
   Note: For company-internal apps, scopes aren't listed on the consent screen and use of restricted or sensitive scopes does not require further review by Google.
   ...

Indeed, I am running a "Quickstart". However, I *CANNOT* select 'Internal', the option is disabled to me. Hovering over the option displays the pop-up text: "Because you are not a Google Workspace User, you can only only make your application available to external (general audience) users."

I don't know... did I miss something here? Something I need to do in order to become a "Google Workspace User", maybe?  That doesn't seem to be listed as a prerequisite.

I tried to Google "How to enable Google Workspace User", that seems to lead to pages that imply I have to purchase Google Domains.

At this point, I'm just trying to run the basic script in the Quickstart.
The code pukes saying file not found for "credentials.json" - that's what led me to find this article: https://github.com/googleworkspace/python-samples/issues/134
that clued me in that I had missed this step to "create credentials for a desktop application".

I would love to start writing Python scripts that can read/write Google Sheets.
I'm stuck on how to get this OAuth consent screen configured.

I tried to continue down the path by Selecting external users, but when trying to add myself as a test user, it complained that I could not add ineligible users.  Again, I'm confused - as the project creator and owner, seems like I should be an eligible user to test the app? Something is not right here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks! ;)

Comment: i didn't catch were you are stuck then. Is it the item 8, when you add a support email?

Comment: If I am strictly following the Quickstart instructions, then it is Step #6 where it says to select "Internal". I can't select that option.

Comment: Is your project under a organization? If not, you won't be able to use that option

Comment: @user1441004, Ok, I understood that. It was the step after. You continue with external, and you has been stuck later on. At which step? the 8th?

Comment: That tutorial is old and hasn't been updated since the change to workspace.   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qwqJcyLQSSQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### You can't select an "Internal" project unless you have a Workspace account

The idea with these types of projects is that they are available for members of your organization/domain. This has the effect of not requiring you to pass the necessary OAuth screen verification that any apps available to the general public have to go through. That is, if you want your app to be public, it has to be reviewed by a 3rd party to ensure that the code is not a security or privacy hazard. This is done at the expense of the developer.

So you'll have to set it to "External" - just make sure you add yourself and any accounts that will be using it as "testing" users so that you have access.

#### Why you are getting the `credentials.json` error.

Have you downloaded the credentials json file?

[image]

You will need to download it, rename it to `credentials.json` and then add it to your project folder so that Python can see it.

Note, this issue is not due to the OAuth consent screen. To get to that stage, to know if you have configured it correctly, the script needs the data within the `credentials.json` to be able to request a authentication to Google's servers. When this request is made, it should give you a link to the OAuth consent screen which will then ask you for the appropriate permissions.

#### References

- [internal vs external](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/10311615?hl=en)